# Error with Springboot 2.4.0 incompatible versions

Tags: spring-boot

I have followed the below link and have updated the dependent jar versions respectively for [spring boot 2.4.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html#dependency-versions).

But I get the following error while starting the service:

```
o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. 
Message: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcMetricsFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/web/servlet/WebMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'webMvcMetricsFilter' parameter 0;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'newRelicMeterRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/export/newrelic/NewRelicMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'newRelicMeterRegistry' parameter 2;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'newRelicClientProvider' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/export/newrelic/NewRelicMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [io.micrometer.newrelic.NewRelicClientProvider]: 
Factory method 'newRelicClientProvider' threw exception; nested exception is io.micrometer.core.instrument.config.validate.ValidationException: Multiple validation failures:
management.metrics.export.newrelic.apiKey was 'null' but it is required when publishing to Insights API
management.metrics.export.newrelic.accountId was 'null' but it is required when publishing to Insights API
```

So, I would like to understand where I will get compatible versions while upgrading to 2.4.0?

For example, I have updated these versions:

```
io.micrometer.micrometer-core                          // v1.6.2
io.micrometer.micrometer-registry-new-relic            // v1.6.2  
io.micrometer.micrometer-registry-prometheus           // v1.6.2
spring.cloud.version                                   // v2020.0.0-M6
org.springframework.cloud.spring-cloud-starter-sleuth  // v2.2.5.RELEASE
redisson.version                                       // v3.12.2
```

Comment: Can you show the whole build.gradle or pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the use of "io.micrometer.micrometer-registry-new-relic" api. But the problem looks like some validations are getting failed because of wrong value. Make sure your registry parameters are correct to get through the validations. Below is napshot of error from your error log.
nested exception is io.micrometer.core.instrument.config.validate.ValidationException: Multiple validation failures: management.metrics.export.newrelic.apiKey was 'null' but it is required when publishing to Insights API management.metrics.export.newrelic.accountId was 'null' but it is required when publishing to Insights API.

Also refer below link if that can help.
https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/error-with-micrometer-and-newrelic-with-springboot2/55988